# Searching MYSQL with multiple words and ordering by relevency

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a program in PHP where users submit a file and then can search for the file based off of 6 categories that they entered when they initially created the file. The categories are stored in a table in one cell that looks like this:
           category_1 category_2 category_3 *etc* - they are not in separate columns

I need to create a page where the user can fill in the categories that they want to search by and then submit the query to the MYSQL database. I want the page to sort the rows by which files match the most categories first.

My question is how to I set up the MYSQL query to search for 6 categories and then order the results by the rows that have the most categories matched (show the one with 3 matched categories in front of the one with 2 categories matched?

I would put up code that I tried, but I don't even know where to start (do I use regular expressions?). Any help would be great. I am familiar with PHP and HTML, but MYSQL is new to me.

Comment: You're going to have a really hard time ordering by relevancy. IF it isn't imperative better give it up

Comment: Thats gonna be quite hard, since the categories are in one cell and not multiple columns...

Comment: Can you please share your code. I will try to help.

Comment: You really should put your categories in separate columns or have a lookup table with the file id and the category - indexed by category. Efficient database design is key here.

Answer (score 0):

You should investigate using MySQL's FULLTEXT search in boolean mode.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Especially when you have your categories concatenated together in a single column, this is very likely a good way to solve your problem.

You'll need to use MyISAM for the access method for the table or tables you search this way.

(Be careful: if you don't use Boolean mode fulltext search is hard to test on a small table; its sensing of word frequencies for a small text corpus yields unpredictable results. But with Boolean mode you'll be fine.)

Answer (score 0):

Lets say the categories are in a column called @Categories.  For convenience, I'm going to assume that they are comma separated, rather than space separated (you can just use replace in the following code).  This simplifies the explanation.

```
select
from files f
order by (find_in_list(reverse(substring_index(reverse(substring_index(@Categories, ',', 1))), ',' 1), f.categories) > 0) +
      (find_in_list(reverse(substring_index(reverse(substring_index(@Categories, ',', 2)), ',' 1)), f.categories) > 0) +
      (find_in_list(reverse(substring_index(reverse(substring_index(@Categories, ',', 3)), ',' 1)), f.categories) > 0) +
      (find_in_list(reverse(substring_index(reverse(substring_index(@Categories, ', ', 4), ',' 1)), f.categories) > 0) +
      (find_in_list(reverse(substring_index(reverse(substring_index(@Categories, ',', 5)), ',' 1)), f.categories) > 0) +
      (find_in_list(reverse(substring_index(reverse(substring_index(@Categories, ',', 6)), ',' 1)), f.categories) > 0) desc
```

(Note:  This is untested.)

The key to this is the expression:

```
      (find_in_list(reverse(substring_index(reverse(substring_index(@Categories, ',', <n>)), ',' 1)), f.categories) > 0) +
```

Let's explain this inside out:

The expression `substring_index(@Categories, ',', <n>)` returns the categories string up to the the nth category.

The `reverse` then reverses this string, so the nth one is now first.

The next `substring_index` returns the first element of this string, which is the nth element of the original string.  But, it is reversed, so hence the next `reverse`.  Finally, the `find_in_set()` looks for this in the categories on the file.

The entire `order by` clause adds these values together (booleans add up like integers in MySQL).  So, you get the count of matches -- which is how you want to order the original data.

All that said, this is a lousy structure for the data.  If you stored this in a more normalized form, the solution would be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
 select 
    id, 
    name, sum(
       IF(find_in_set('$cat1', replace(' ',',','categories'), 1, 0) +
       IF(find_in_set('$cat2', replace(' ',',','categories'), 1, 0) +
       IF(find_in_set('$cat3', replace(' ',',','categories'), 1, 0) +
       IF(find_in_set('$cat4', replace(' ',',','categories'), 1, 0) +
       IF(find_in_set('$cat5', replace(' ',',','categories'), 1, 0) +
       IF(find_in_set('$cat6', replace(' ',',','categories'), 1, 0)) as match_score
 from products
    where match_score > 0 
 order by match_score desc;
```